How to correctly create npm package with multiple entrypoints
I'm writing my own project on VUE version 3 (+TS). I moved some utility classes to a separate NPM library. My library is assembled into several JS files (one for each class) + all exports from these files are re-exported to index.js:
import StorageService from './lib/storageService';
import TransportService from './lib/transportService';
import TokenService from './lib/tokenService';
import AuthService from './lib/authService';

const myServices = {
  StorageService,
  TransportService,
  TokenService,
  AuthService,
};

export { myServices as default, StorageService, TransportService, TokenService, AuthService };

The library's package.json file is as follows:
// .....
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "src",
    "dist/*",
    "index.d.ts",
    "auth-service.d.ts",
    "token-service.d.ts",
    "storage-service.d.ts",
    "transport-service.d.ts"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js",
      "type": "./dist/index.d.js"
    },
    "./authService": {
      "import": "./dist/auth-service.js",
      "type": "./dist/auth-service.d.js"
    },
    "./tokenService": {
      "import": "./dist/token-service.js",
      "type": "./dist/token-service.d.js"
    },
    "./storageService": {
      "import": "./dist/storage-service.js",
      "type": "./dist/storage-service.d.js"
    },
    "./transportService": {
      "import": "./dist/transport-service.js",
      "type": "./dist/transport-service.d.js"
    }
  },
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.js"

I'm installing my NPM package. If I import classes from index.js - everything works as it should. But if I want to import a specific class from the corresponding JS file from my lib, I get an error in WebStorm: Vue: Cannot find module my-services/transportService or its corresponding type declarations.
import { TransportService } from 'my-services';
// First version: This works

import TransportService from 'my-services/transportService';
// Second version: In this case, I get an error in WebStorm: Vue: Cannot find module my-services/transportService or its corresponding type declarations.

In this case, the application build passes, and everything works in both: the first and second versions! But in the second option, WebStorm highlights the import and does not understand the types that come from the imported module (which negates the typescript typing).
What am I doing wrong? And what is the correct way to assemble/design a library with several entrypoints? (I’m new to this, and I still need to make a separate library of components, and there I also really want to decompose groups of components that are common in meaning into separate entrypoints).
I found a description of a similar problem on the Internet, and they suggest setting the Vue Service parameter in the Vue Language Server (Volar) in the Typescript/VUE Webstorm settings. I did that, but it didn't help me. :(
Also I set in the file tsconfig.json:
  "compilerOptions": {
     "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
     .....
  }

But that didn't help me either
